# Convert multidimensional list to a normal list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

Im creating a multiprocessing script that update ids by a post request. There are some ids that fail to update because the high amount of requests and I store them in a list with an strange result.

My first list of ids:

```
[169088, 169402, 169450, 170407, 169644, 170228, 171544, 169609, 170519, 169647, 169868, 169602, 170492, 169366, 169368, 169369, 169372, 170236, 171516, 169685]
```

Result:

```
[[], [169402], [], [170228], [], [169609], [], [169647], [169868], [169602], [170492], [169366], [169368], [169369], [169372], [170236], [171516], [169685]]
```

Expected result:

```
 [169402, 170228, , 169609, 169647, 169868, 169602, 170492, 169366, 169368, 169369, 169372, 170236, 71516, 169685]
```

I tried with a for that loop the list but I obtain `[]`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue:

If the array is:

```
array_of_fails = [[], [169402], [], [170228], [], [169609], [], [169647], [169868], [169602], [170492], [169366], [169368], [169369], [169372], [170236], [171516], [169685]]
```

Solution:

```
import itertools

chain = list(itertools.chain(*array_of_fails))
chain = [169402, 170228, , 169609, 169647, 169868, 169602, 170492, 169366, 169368, 169369, 169372, 170236, 71516, 169685]
```